# Linux music server player for YouTube playlists with remote control

Tags: linux, web-apps, music, youtube

Does anyone know a good server music player, with support of YouTube playlists and has a good web frontend?

Like Mopidy and https://github.com/dz0ny/mopidy-youtube. Unfortunately, it plays playlist like a whole podcast stream.

Atraci is great, but it is available only as desktop application.

Something like madsonic (subsonic), ampache or mopidy.

- webui
- android remote apk
- support of youtube playlists/channels

I would like to play music from my favorites yt channels on my htpc and control it through android app.

Comment: What is a "music server player"?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.